# how can modify js file a web game

Tags: javascript, typescript

where can I find the js file of a web game to reverse engineer it and make a hack like Krunker not exactly like this hacke but how do I like this one

I hacked some based games with cheat engine but some game I couldn't hack it
so I tried to modfiy some js web games but I don't know where can I find js files
I tried to inspect the page and see all the js files and I could not find them and I inspect the page and go to the networks in the dev tool

Comment: There is no way for us to know how/where files are stored or how they are structured on this unknown game.